# indicator is not working in loadmask sencha touch

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have applied load-mask at controller level.i have added custom message like "loading...". for the uses reference this will indicate, the page is loading. also i have set indicator:true. but i am not able to see the indicator. please any one help me. how to show the indicator to user.

My code is Here:

```
OnInitCompanyPage: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.setMasked({ xtype: 'loadmask', message: 'Loading...', indicator:true});
            Ext.data.JsonP.request({
                url: SLS.BRND.WEB.common.Constants.wcfBaseUrl + 'PropertyService.svc/GetCompanyDetail',              
                method: 'POST',
                callbackkey: 'callback',
                params: {
                    format: 'json'
                },
                callback: function (response, value, request) {
                    var localdata = JSON.stringify(value);
                    localStorage.setItem('PromoURL', localdata);
                    Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
                },
                failure: function (response, request) {
                }
            });             
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

i am using sass style. in sass folder app.scss does not contain the keyword. **@include sencha-loading-spinner;** now i have added this one and complied.. now indicator is working fine and visible to see.

Comment: Yep, been there as well. It took me one hour to figure it out.

Comment: + 2 more hours wasted on this one - thanks a million for pointing this out.

Comment: I have the same issue as well! In my app.scss i didn't have @include sencha-loading-spinner; as well. But when i added it, it didnt work, and also it did alter the look of my app : s

Answer (score 3):

In latest versions the mixin **sencha-loading-spinner** had been renamed to **st-loading-spinner,** so now you need to add to your *app.scss*

```
@include st-loading-spinner;
```